# Pick-up Soccer in Dublin

Tags: ireland, socializing, dublin, football

I'm going to Dublin on vacation for a few days at the end of November. I am hoping to play in a very casual soccer game or two while I am there. Does anyone know of good places to find welcoming "pick-up" (as we say in the USA) soccer games in the city or nearby?

Comment: I don't play football much, but you could try going down to a football pitch and asking people currently playing if you can join in? People are often willing to meet new people

Answer (score 8):

After quite some searching, the best I can provide is [a link on gumtree](http://dublin.gumtree.ie/f-soccer-Community-sports-sports-partners-W0QQCatIdZ8033QQKeywordZsoccer) which shows classified ads for soccer in Dublin.

Several of them are trying to form teams or need extra players, and I'm sure would be happy to have a visitor join in for a game!